# Javascript method undefined

Tags: javascript, signalr

im quite new to OOP in javascript
 and here is my external js file.

```
(function ($, connection) {    
"use strict";

var conn = connection.serverHub;
connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:51283/signalr';

function trackUser(username, roleid, sessionid, ipaddress) {
    var page = document.location.pathname;        
    conn.server.joinUser(username, roleid, ipaddress, page, sessionid).done();
}

// signalr client method
conn.client.receivedNotification = function (item) {
    alert(item);
    conn.server.notifiedUser().done();
};
$(function () {
    connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        trackUser('<%= session("USERNAME")%>', '<%= session("ROLE")%>', '<%= Session.SessionID%>', '<%=Request.UserHostAddress%>');//da attivare solo in produzione
    }).fail(function () { alert("failed"); });
}); }(jQuery, $.connection));
```

and this is how i call my method

```
<body>
<script src="http://localhost:51283/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:51283/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:51283/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script src="myexternaljs.js"></script>
<script>
    trackUser('<%= session("USERNAME")%>', '<%= session("ROLE")%>', '<%= Session.SessionID%>', '<%=Request.UserHostAddress%>');//da attivare solo in produzione
</script>
</body>
```

when i tried to call trackUser method and i'm getting trackUser in not defined

where i did wrong?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is defined inside an anonymous scope (`function ($, connection) {  }`). It will not be accessible outside of that scope. You could create a global variable, and assign your function to that:

```
window.trackUser = function(username, roleid, sessionid, ipaddress) {
   ...
};
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with signalr, but I assume it'll work just fine if you define it exactly like you have, only replacing `function trackUser` with `window.trackUser = function`.

Answer (score 0):

It is undefined, because it is not in the global scope. Either add `window.trackUser = trackUser` inside your anonymous function or move your function declaration to the global scope.